# need oracle sql query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a simple problem.

I have a table like this:

```
Employee id -  Debit - Credit
    1      -   100  -  null
    1      -   200  -  null
    1      -   300  -  null
    1      -   null -  700
    1      -   null -  800
    1      -   null -  900
```

i want a query that generates the result like this

```
EmpId -credit - Debit
 1    -  100    -  700
 1    -  200    -  800
 1    -  300    -  900
```

thanks in advance for anybody who can help .

Comment: How do you know which values to pair?

Comment: What other columns do you have in the table, some kind of transaction id or date perhaps?

Comment: You need another column to tie a specific `credit` to a specific `debit`. Does your table lacks such a column? Also, is the data **guaranteed** to have matched pairs, with no hanging `credit` or `debit` records?

Comment: What makes you ***certain*** that the 100 credit doesn't go with the 900 debit? Or any other combinations?

Answer (score 0):

This query builds two subqueries, one for CREDIT one for DEBIT. It uses analytic `row_number()` function to fake a joining column for each, based on the value of the amount: the lowest CREDIT is paired to the lowest DEBIT, and so on. The subqueries are FULL OUTER JOINed to handle hanging values.**(*)**

```
select coalesce (cr.employee_id, db.employee_id) as employee_id
       , cr.Credit
       , db.Debit
from ( select employee_id
             , credit
             , row_number() over (partition by employee_id order by credit) as rn
       from your_table
       where credit is not null ) cr
full outer join 
      ( select employee_id
             , debit
             , row_number() over (partition by employee_id order by debit) as rn
       from your_table
       where debit is not null )
on cr.employee_id = db.employee_id
and cr.rn = db.rn
order by 1, 2, 3
/
```

---

**(*)**  Obviously if your actual table includes such a joining column and you just didn't include it in your question then you should substitute that column instead. Same if you have a more appropriate column for ordering the OVER clause, such as a transaction date.